# TypeError: authClient.request is not a function

Tags: node.js

I have been struggling to find a resolution to the following error:

```
 TypeError: authClient.request is not a function",
    at Object.createAPIRequest 
(/app/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/lib/apirequest.js:179:20)",
    at Object.watch (/app/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis/gmail/v1.js:108:37)",
    at Strategy.GoogleStrategy [as _verify] (/app/lib/oauth2.js:96:28)",
    at /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:193:24",
    at /app/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:122:5",
    at passBackControl (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:134:9)",
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>
(/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)",
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:165:20)",
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)",
    at /app/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31",
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)"
```

I am using nodejs and the googleapis library.

The error happens when I call the

gmail.user.watch(); method.

Here is my **app.js**

I have setup sessions and oauth2 when the user hits /login

```
'use strict';


const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const express = require('express');
const MemcachedStore = require('connect-memcached')(session);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const uid = require('uid-safe')

const passport = require('passport');

const config = require('./config');
const logging = require('./lib/logging');

const app = express();

app.disable('etag');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('trust proxy', true);

// Add the request logger before anything else so that it can
// accurately log requests.
app.use(logging.requestLogger);    


// Configure the session and session storage.
const sessionConfig = session({
  genid: function(req) {
    return uid.sync(18) // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: config.get('SECRET'),
  signed: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false
  },
  store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: db })
});
app.use(sessionConfig);


// Mongo

// OAuth2
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(require('./lib/oauth2').router);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
```

**oauth2.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const config = require('../config');
const client = require('./client/client');
const session = require('express-session')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:outrigger@ds227168.mlab.com:27168/outrigger')
var connection = mongoose.connection;
console.log('Connected!');

// [START setup]
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const google = require('googleapis')


// Configure the Google strategy for use by Passport.js.
//
// OAuth 2-based strategies require a `verify` function which receives the
// credential (`accessToken`) for accessing the Google API on the user's behalf,
// along with the user's profile. The function must invoke `cb` with a user
// object, which will be set at `req.user` in route handlers after
// authentication.
var oauth2 = new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: config.get('OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID'),
  clientSecret: config.get('OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET'),
  callbackURL: config.get('OAUTH2_CALLBACK'),
  accessType: 'online'
}, (res, req, profile, cb) => {
  // Extract the minimal profile information we need from the profile object
  // provided by Google
  cb(null, extractProfile(profile));     

});

passport.use(oauth2);

passport.serializeUser((user, cb) => {
  cb(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((obj, cb) => {
  cb(null, obj);
});

// [END setup]

const router = express.Router();



function onSignIn(){
  client.outrigger();
}

// Begins the authorization flow. The user will be redirected to Google where
// they can authorize the application to have access to their basic profile
// information. Upon approval the user is redirected to `/auth/google/callback`.
// If the `return` query parameter is specified when sending a user to this URL
// then they will be redirected to that URL when the flow is finished.
// [START authorize]
router.get(
  // Login url
  '/auth/login',

  // Save the url of the user's current page so the app can redirect back to
  // it after authorization
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.query.return) {
      req.session.oauth2return = req.query.return;
    }
    next();
  },

  // Start OAuth 2 flow using Passport.js
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: [
    'email',
    'profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 
    'https://mail.google.com/', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts'
  ]},
    function (err, user, info){
      if (err){
        console.log("Error: " + err);
      }
      else if(!user) {
        console.log('User not authed');
      }
    }));
// [END authorize]

// [START callback]
router.get(
  // OAuth 2 callback url. Use this url to configure your OAuth client in the
  // Google Developers console
  '/auth/google/callback',

  // Finish OAuth 2 flow using Passport.js
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  // Redirect back to the original page, if any
  (req, res) => {
    // Save token
    const redirect = req.session.oauth2return || '/';
    delete req.session.oauth2return;
    res.redirect(redirect);


    console.log(req.session.id);
    onSignIn();



    //})
  }
);
// [END callback]
```

When I call the client.outrigger(); method in the callback section. It will call

```
gmail.user.watch({
  'userId': 'me',
  'auth': oauth2, // imported above
  resource: {
      topicName: "projects/outrigger/topics/gmail",
      labelIds: ["INBOX"]
    }
});
```

I have been looking around the internet for a solution to no avail. I hope I can figure this out.

You can find the site live at https://outrigger.herokuapp.com/

I have seen people saying to check the scopes. The scopes we are using will work acording to googles documentation of the gmail api.

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a minimal example - no one is going to read hundreds of lines of code for this

Comment: @Avery I️ shrunk down the code. Hope I️t is more readable now.

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?